# Check a variable is a multiple of 10

Tags: python

I need my program to check an in putted variable (e_gtin) and then calculate the GTIN from it (times the 1,3,5 and 7th number by three then add the 7 numbers up and divide by the nearest 10 times table) So far, it times the numbers and adds them up but I don't know where to go from there in terms of making it a multiple of ten

In Addition i eventually used this code

```
calculator = int(e_gtin[0])*3+int(e_gtin[1])+\
         int(e_gtin[2])*3+int(e_gtin[3])+\
         int(e_gtin[4])*3+int(e_gtin[5])+\
         int(e_gtin[6])*3   

rounding = round(calculator+4)
```

The plus 4 is so the variable will always round up rather than rounding down (The GTIN calculation specifies this)

e_gtin being an inputted 7 digit GTIN code.

Thanks go to ---> 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/906693/roadrunner66

Comment: You're looking for the [modulo](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) (`%`) operator. You can use it in conjunction with the division operator (`/`) to determine the remainder of a division operation—with that information you should be able to find the nearest multiple of ten.

Comment: To round a number to the nearest 10, just use `round(number, -1)`

Comment: Thanks, I'd completely forgotten the round module :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are presumably asking about calculating the check-digit on a GTIN8 number. An explanation is given here http://www.gs1.org/how-calculate-check-digit-manually

```
e  = input("Enter a 7 digit number - ")

# note: an integer number can not be accessed like a string or list, 
# make it a string first
e=str(e)
sum= int(e[0])*3+int(e[1])+\
     int(e[2])*3+int(e[3])+\
     int(e[4])*3+int(e[5])+\
     int(e[6])*3

checkdigit = 9 - (sum-1) % 10
print sum,checkdigit
```

To understand the working of a the modulo operator, just play with it, make yourself a table etc.

```
import numpy as np
sums=np.array([50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61])
print sums
print sums % 10
print 10 - sums % 10  # all results right except for 10s which should be zeros
print 10 - (sums-1) % 10   -1
```

output:

```
[50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1]
[10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 10  9]
[0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9]
```

Comment: Ahhhh, ok! Thanks, this has been a big help